# Отступы между элементами flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

```css
.text-content {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-content">

  <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
  
  <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae,
  nesciunt iusto, vero neque harum accusamus iste unde illum ratione voluptates perferendis
  autem sunt eius aspernatur animi a eligendi labore cupiditate.</p>
  
</div>
```

Нужно добавить отступ 50px между Заголовком и Параграфом (которые расположены горизонтально в flex-контейнере) за счет уменьшения Параграфа (а не Заголовка). Плюс нужно уместиться в ширину 600px - нельзя увеличить

Пробовал:

- gap: 50px (не подходит - уменьшается заголовок)
- margin-right: 50px для заголовка  (не подходит - уменьшается заголовок)
- margin-left: 50px для параграфа (просто не работает - никакого отступа даже не появляется)
- flex-basis для заголовка + gap: 50px (снова уменьшает заголовок - я уже перестал понимать как работает basis)
- flex-basis для заголовка + margin-right: 50px (снова уменьшает заголовок)
- flex-basis для параграфа + margin-left: 50px (никакой реакции)
- пробовал читать про семантические отступы margin-block-start и т.д. - вроде не мой случай
- пробовал flex-inline-ы на крайний случай
- менял display-и и параграфу, и заголовку

Знаю, что можно использовать костыль через обертку в div-ы, но это не дело((

Я подумывал, что возможно проблема в параграфе как теге, пытался найти особенность flexbox-а для параграфов и заголовков - ничего не нашел.

Comment: Попробуйте свойства `flex-shrink` и `flex-basis`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-content {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  min-width: 230px;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-content">

  <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
  
  <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae,
  nesciunt iusto, vero neque harum accusamus iste unde illum ratione voluptates perferendis
  autem sunt eius aspernatur animi a eligendi labore cupiditate.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Действительно, работает в редакторе
Но на моей странице это НЕ работает.
Этот flex-контейнер находится внутри ячейки grid (если это важно)